# Plugin.Firebase throws a NullReferenceException

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, maui

In my .Net MAUI app, I use Plugin.Firebase to send information to Google Analytics (GA4).

Here is the code:

```
    if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS || DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
    {
        if (AgreeToAnalytics)
        {
            var sut = CrossFirebaseAnalytics.Current;

            sut.LogEvent(gaEvent, parameters);
        }
    }
```

For Android, calling LogEvent() throws an exception:

> Plugin.Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsImplementation.LogEvent(String
> eventName, IDictionary`2 parameters) System.NullReferenceException:
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is how it looks in the log:

> 10-17 13:12:33.857 10916 10916 F mono-rt : [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED
> EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
> an instance of an object. 10-17 13:12:33.857 10916 10916 F mono-rt :
> at
> Plugin.Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsImplementation.LogEvent(String
> eventName, IDictionary`2 parameters)

The parameters I pass are not null. "eventName" is a string, and "parameters" contains one key/value pair, and both key and value are strings that are not null.

I reported an issue to the author of the plugin (https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/203), but did not get any answer.

It used to work in the past, so I wonder if migrating to .Net 7 from 6 had anything to do with the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

> migrate app to .Net 7 from 6

You can refer to this sample: [MAUI DotNet 7 simple sample](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/204#issuecomment-1763501986).

**Second**

> Plugin.Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsImplementation.LogEvent(String eventName, IDictionary`2 parameters) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

You can try to [add Plugin.Firebase.Analytics explicitly to your .csproj file](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/10#issuecomment-819504724):

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase.Analytics" Version="2.0.1"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

**Third**

In addition, there is an issue([Possible nullpointer](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/18)) with the same situation as yours, but the author closed it. You can ask him.